# Inline Javascript works but not when external

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this short Javascript code that I want to put in a external file. The reason being is because there will be many .htm pages that would use it. So instead of putting it all inline at every single file, I want to put it in an external file.

But the thing is, it doesn't work. The script is basically a "back to top" button. It works flawlessly when I put the script in the `.htm` file. Another note by the way, I'm loading the `.htm` file in a `Div`, could that cause problems? Edit: The file is loaded through the `.load()` jQuery function.

I have also tried putting the script inline in my `index.html` but it fails to work there too.

Here is the code:

```
$('.backtotopwrapper').click(function(){
  $('body,html').animate({scrollTop: "0px"},1500);
});
```

Update: I have tested my other .js code and the ones that have nothing to do with the .htm file work. The code that is specific to the elements inside the .htm is the only one that doesn't work.

Comment: When you put it in an external file is it a .js file that you link to in the HEAD of your document or at the end of your document just before the close body tag? Wherever it comes is your jquery.js file being loaded before it? Also are you executing the js above on document ready?

Comment: I link it at the Head of my document. I forgot to mention that it's loaded on document ready when it is inline... Wait does it mean that I have to put the document ready tag inside the .js file too?

Comment: Yeah, you should place all jQuery snippets like the one you're using in one external .js file and have them all wrapped inside one instance the document ready code in there too.

Comment: Doh! That was silly of me, but still it doesn't work. I have this sickly feeling it has something do with the DOM.

Comment: You need not put it in document.ready if you are adding the script in the body.

Comment: In case you're inserting .htm files in that mentioned div with ajax, you must use .live() or .on() function. Otherwise, those .htm pages will not know about scripts you've loaded.

Comment: I'm adding the script in the header, but that's good to know too theshadowmonkey! Okay I tested around with my other js code and put them in the external js file and they work. The only one that doesn't work is the .htm specific code.

Comment: Try using .on() like this $('.backtotopwrapper').on('click', function(){}); for dynamically added elements for event delegation...

Comment: @MiljanPuzović The .htm file is loaded through the .load() function from jquery.

Comment: Use `console.log()` in Chrome or Firefox with Firebug to test your setup.

Comment: That is it. You must use .live() function inside .on()

Comment: @MiljanPuzović .live() is deprecated. use .on() for proper delegation

Comment: Do not use `$.live()`; it is deprecated due to poor design and removed in 1.9. `$.on()` showed up in 1.4.3, for versions before that use `$.delegate()` instead.

Comment: My mistake, i meant .load() but wrote .live() :)

Comment: @Banzboy see your source code and verify if the code is actually on the page and do a console.log() after the event

Comment: @theshadowmonkey : `$('.backtotopwrapper').on('click', function(){});` won't do event delegation. The correct format should be `$("body").on('click', '.backtotopwrapper',function(){});`

Comment: @JaredFarrish : `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

Comment: @JFK I meant he can also use it for event delegation, didnt get a way to point that out....will the edit the comment thanks :)

Comment: @JFK - Of course you're right, `$.delegate()` showed up in 1.4.2.

Comment: @JFK, I think he needs to load .htm files on document ready/page load, not on click event.

Comment: @JaredFarrish : apologies if it sounds annoying but `$.delegate()` doesn't exist, it's simply `.delegate()`

Comment: @JFK - That's how I and others reference `jQuery.func()` for some time, so I'm not quite sure what you're stating about simplicity. This comment stream is getting a bit overloaded with noisy blather as well. `:)`

Comment: @MiljanPuzović : not sure what "he" needs (yet), I am just pointing out other people's incorrect format.

Comment: @JaredFarrish : what I mean is that you could use `$.ajax(//settings)` but not `$.delegate(//parameters)` for instance. Last comment because we already forgot what was the OP's question ;)

Comment: Can you add `console.log($('.backtotopwrapper').length)` before adding the click event so that we can make sure that the event is getting binded

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm getting a 0 in the debugger, that's not good is it.

Comment: nop, can you type the same in your browsers console and check

Comment: Tried it in the console and first it's a 0 and then a 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, 3 files :

- main.html
- loremIpsum2.html
- myScroll.js

1). In *main.html* I call jQuery and *myScroll.js* **external** files
Also I have an empty wrapper *div* (`<div id="loader"></div>`) where I put the contents of *loremIpsum2.html* using jQuery `.load()` so

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>link to external js file</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="myScroll.js"></script>
  <script>
  /* <![CDATA[ */
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#loader").load("loremIpsum2.html");
   }); // ready​​​
  /* ]]> */
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="wrap">
   <div id="loader"></div>
  </div><!--wrap-->
 </body> 
</html>
```

2). In *loremIpsum2.html*, I have just a bunch of paragraphs but at the end I have my button :

```
<a class="backtotopwrapper" href="javascript:;">go to top</a>
```

3). In *myScroll.js* i Have the function for my scrolling button :

```
$(function () {
    $('body').on("click", ".backtotopwrapper", function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 1500);
    });
});
```

Since I am loading the file where the button is via `.load()`, I am using `.on()` in its delegated form.

See **[DEMO](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/CSS_externalJSfile_25mar13.html)** and feel free to explore the source code.

**NOTE** : `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but didn't perform any solution mentioned here, i actually dicovered what made it work for me when my external scripts werent working but the same code works internally.

Just remove any spaces/special characters from your external script filename e.g instead of calling it "admin-script.js", call it "adminscript.js", without the special characters like the hyphen, then refer to the script with the new name and thats it, it worked for me.

Comment: thanks!. this file name strict took me infinity to find out.